# How to import a table with delimiter ";" into hive?

Tags: csv, hadoop, hive, delimiter

I tried to import a CSV file with delimiter ";" into Hive, but I cannot create a Hive table with ";" as delimiter. Instead, I changed the delimiter of csv file to "," and imported it to hive, but I am getting null values in the integer field.

Answer (score 1):

Try using "\073" instead of ";". It should be working.

Ex:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE example(id String,name String) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY "\073" 
LINES TERMINATED BY "\n" 
STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION "/home/location";
```